# Find the distribution of sum of square of normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,1)$,
Evaluate the density function / distribution function of $X_1^2+X_2^2+\cdots+X_n^2$.

I was trying to associate this with the Chi-square distribution, but there will be $2(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n)$ left following the normal distribution, but it is not independent with the above Chi-square distribution, so I stuck here.
Are there any ways to deal with this problem? Thanks!

Comment: **Hint:** Check out the [Noncentral chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution)